# No Flash Player found. 11.5.0 version required. under ubuntu?

Tags: flash-player

i want to play new games on Facebook but i have the message : No flash player  found 11.5.0requis. It seems that there is no update version for ubuntu. How can y play games? Is ther another solution ?
Thanks
Sorry for my English but i am french.
               Edwigw

Comment: see if these instructions solve it: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-flash-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 3):

The last available Flash for Ubuntu is version 11.2. If you install it from the repos this is what you'll get and as you can see more and more sites are not working with it.

To have the latest version, use [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) browser. It has built-in Flash player. Just download the correct `.deb` for your system and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: This is the better solution IMHO. Chrome automatically updates their flash player and also has additional securities beyond Flash that protect your computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/about.html) will help you get the latest windows version of flash (and other plugins like silverlight) running on your Linux install using wine.